# Wait for Bluebird promise to resolve before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, reddit

I'm using an NPM package called [snoowrap](https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/snoowrap), that accesses the Reddit API. It returns results, such as from searches, as Bluebird promises.

I have file `reddit.js` like this:

```
const snoowrap = require('snoowrap');

function getFirstSearchResultUrl() {
  // Actual Reddit API credentials not included.
  const r = new snoowrap({
    userAgent,
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    username,
    password,
  });

  return r
    .search({
      query: 'query',
      subreddit: 'askreddit',
    })
    .then((posts) => {
      return posts[0].url;
    });
}

const resultUrl = getFirstSearchResultUrl();
console.log(resultUrl);
```

But `console.log` prints `[chainable Promise]` rather than the URL that is returned.

How can I get it to print the URL that was returned, instead of the promise? I looked through the docs and tried different Bluebird methods like `.reflect()` and `.settle()` but they didn't seem to work for me.

Is it possible to prevent the rest of the script from executing until the promise is completed?

Comment: You really should learn about promises in general first.

Comment: `getFirstSearchResult` returns a promise so you either chain a `.then()` stage or if you want to go the imperative way use `await-async` in an async function.

Comment: You *cannot* immediately log the url - it has not arrived yet. All you got is a promise for it, which will fulfill with the url *in the future* - and you can schedule a callback run when it is there: `getFirstSearchResultUrl().then(resultUrl => { console.log(resultUrl); });`

Comment: Is it possible to completely prevent the rest of the script from executing until the promise is resolved? Or I'll just have to put everything that requires its results in the `then` callback function?

Comment: No.. it's synchronous workflow. Even if you could, as @Bergi says you can not assign the resolution of a promise to a variable just like that. You either chain the promise with `.then()` or use the [async-await abstraction](https://developer.mozillhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_functiona.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Okay  thanks, I'll use `then()` then. I also tried `async` and `await` and it works well too.

Comment: I just noticed comment section :p Everything is already there.  should I remove my answer or leave it @Gray ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Answer's fine, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getFirstSearchResultUrl()` returns a promise. That's why you see that log statement printed. And promise is not resolved yet.

So,You can wait for it to resolve with `async/await` or you can log the returned results adding a callback to `.then()` with `getFirstSearchResultUrl()`.

Something like `getFirstSearchResultUrl().then(url=> console.log(url))`

You can also `await` for your `getFirstSearchResultUrl()` to be resolved, get the results and log it

Something like

```
(async function(){
  var url  =  await getFirstSearchResultUrl();
  console.log(url);
})();
```

Comment: It's the same as using `.then` - no blocking.

Comment: @destoryer thanks for that.  wasn't clear about that

Comment: Really no reason at all for `async/await` here.  Simpler and perhaps more explanatory to a newbie to just use `.then()` on the returned promise.